# Disable visit to page by direct link .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I want visitors not to be able to go to the page http://test.com/test.php when they typ in into the browser. The following code would help me with this in my .htaccess file:

```
<Files .test.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

However, I want users to be able to visit this page when they click on a button on a different page on the website redirecting them to http://test.com/test.php. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to to rely on `HTTP_REFERER` for this. Place this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule test\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Change `domain.com` to your actual domain.